# How can "PermitRootLogin no" add security

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

The topic is already discussed [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-is-the-effect-of-permitrootlogin-no), but I don't fully understand the answers

I am trying to meet some good practice security criteria while setting up a VPS. I am using Ubuntu18 on AWS EC2 which I ssh into via `ssh -i <myfile.pem> <user@IPv4>`

So what's the technical background about considering `PermitRootLogin no` in the sshd_config?
As discussed, it will disable the option to login in directly as root via SSH, but I don't see the point when I can do `sudo -s` e.g. anyway.

I heard some explanation which said that even if my private key leaks, I still need to root login with a password, but on my current EC2 setup there is no password authentification when I do `sudo -s`.

Redundant: After default setup in the sshd_config is written `#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` (commented out so per default set to yes) Even if I change this to no, I can still login to root without password.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the root account for ssh login increases the security of the machine because anyone trying to brute-force the ssh system now has to guess a valid user name as well.

That is the reason, even though you can get root level access with sudo from your user account.

Incidentally, I suggest setting sudo to require a password by editing the /etc/sudoers file with the visudo command.

Answer (score 3):

I think the thing that is causing you the most confusion, is you are trying to rationalize the setting based on the way the rest of your particular system is configured (like the fact that sudo has been installed and configured). SSH is used on all kinds of systems from weighty ubuntu desktops, to headless servers, to tiny embedded busybox instances. There is no universal default config across all those platforms. the distro maintainers usually customize config based on their goals.

So another thing to consider is that root isn't just an admin account. comparing to windows its closer to the System account than the predefined Administrator account, which has considerably less access to the OS than root does.

With Root so overpowered, its a good best practice to prevent use of Root (like ubuntu has), and instead use an account with better safety rails. Tools like Sudo can assist with that, but most distros leave it to you to lock it down.

Another concern for root, is that like the windows built-in Administrator, it is a named account that everyone has, and is thus susceptible to brute-force attack. you can't rename root the way you can Administrator, so disabling it, or limiting the ability of a remote user to try to break it is valuable. At least with another account, they'd have to guess both the username and password correctly to get in.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head... "*trying to rationalize the setting based on the way the rest of your particular system is configured*". Even the fact they can `sudo -s` with no password prompt means someone configured `sudoers` file to allow that account to run a specific command without elevation prompt, right. I definitely configure my Linux distro server lockdowns even more for my needs too like requiring all SSH use key pair auth and password adding the public keys I allow, etc.